# NoClassDefFoundError - Only on marshmallow

Tags: java, android

After a recent commit, my app started crashing on marshmallow. I added a custom class, `NormalMode`, which is created when a service is started. The bug only occurs when this service is started.

I tried looking into the 65K limit and tried to used multidex, but it didn't make a difference. I also installed a plugin to tell me how many methods I use, it found 54996 methods.

Here is a sample of the logcat, running an emulator:

```
02-15 18:00:44.428 8783-8783/com.vivescere.beacon I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.vivescere.beacon.emitter.mode.NormalMode>
02-15 18:00:44.429 8783-8783/com.vivescere.beacon D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-15 18:00:44.429 8783-8783/com.vivescere.beacon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vivescere.beacon, PID: 8783
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.vivescere.beacon.emitter.mode.NormalMode
        at com.vivescere.beacon.emitter.EmitterService.switchMode(EmitterService.java:328)
        at com.vivescere.beacon.emitter.EmitterService.start(EmitterService.java:289)
        at com.vivescere.beacon.emitter.EmitterService.onStartCommand(EmitterService.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3010)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-15 18:00:48.441 8783-8783/com.vivescere.beacon I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8783 SIG: 9
```

I tried removing the class in question, but it just slows down the error, which now happens when creating an instance of the next custom class I have.

Comment: did you define the service in the manifest ??

Comment: Have you checked your instant run settings in Android Studio? It may cause  similar issues. Is your service defined as remote in manifest? Check if proguard is enabled, maybe it's messing with your classes. Recheck your multidex setup, maybe you forgot to add something

Comment: The service is properly defined in the manifest, and it was working earler.

Comment: Is is defined as followed: `<service
            android:name=".emitter.EmitterService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />`

Comment: I have proguard enabled, but only in production mode. I'll try checking multidex again. I don't think that instant run is the problem, since I ran my app without it to try.

Comment: I retried multidex, I use it by adding `multiDexEnabled true` to my default config, adding `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to my depencies and adding `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` to my application in the manifest.